# Understanding of css value: 2em 10px

Tags: css

What is the meaning of '2em 10px' in css property value?

Example: `margin: 1em 40px;`

Comment: This depends on the property. Answers can be found in the definitions of the properties in CSS specifications and drafts.

Answer (score 3):

margin accepts one to four arguments:

```
One single value applies to all four sides.
Two values apply first to top and bottom, the second one to left and right.
Three values apply first to top, second to left and right and third to bottom.
Four values apply to top, right, bottom and left in that order (clockwise).
```

you can read the detail here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Answer (score 2):

1em is for top and bottom margin

40px is for left and right margin

1em is equal to the current font size

it could also be written like

```
margin-top: 1em;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-left: 40px;
```

or even another way like

```
margin: 1em 40px 1em 40px;
```

so if the current font size is 24px then the margin would be the same as

```
margin: 24px 40px;
```

but lets say the computer user zooms in on their screen 200% then the margin would be

```
margin: 48px 40px;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3 Org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html), units definition, "em" is defined as

```
"The em is simply the font size. In an element with a 2in font, 1em thus means 2in. Expressing sizes, such as margins and paddings, in em means they are related to the font size, and if the user has a big font (e.g., on a big screen) or a small font (e.g., on a handheld device), the sizes will be in proportion. Declarations such as 'text-indent: 1.5em' and 'margin: 1em' are extremely common in CSS. "
```

while "px" is defined as:

```
"The px unit is the magic unit of CSS. It is not related to the current font and also not related to the absolute units. The px unit is defined to be small but visible, and such that a horizontal 1px wide line can be displayed with sharp edges (no anti-aliasing). What is sharp, small and visible depends on the device and the way it is used: do you hold it close to your eyes, like a mobile phone, at arms length, like a computer monitor, or somewhere in between, like a book? The px is thus not defined as a constant length, but as something that depends on the type of device and its typical use. "**strong text**
```